# how to run adword api from localhost

Tags: google-ads-api

Anyone know how to run google adword api from localhost?
I am using adword( aw_4.6.1 version) php library.

Besides after setting all the things i got the following error

I have run it from command prompt using windows7.

C:\xampp\1.8.0\php>php C:\Apps\xampp\1.8.0\htdocs\aw_4.6.1\examples\Adx\v201309\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php

> An error has occurred: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
>   'adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309/CampaignService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity
>    "adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309/CampaignService?wsdl"

Get the following error. Looking for suggestion.

> An error has occurred: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'adw
>   ords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309/CampaignService?wsdl' : failed to load ex
>   ternal entity "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309/CampaignService
>   ?wsdl"

Comment: check if soap is enabled

Comment: i have solve the problem . in php.ini file i didnt enable ssl . after enabling this i get out from this error.

Comment: You are on a good track looking into SSL. You can also disable SSL verification explicitly, check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41622876/674965

Answer (score 0):

Use before SOAP call:

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
```

I spent several hours searching for solution and this works.